# Way to store data into cookies un-encoded

Tags: angularjs

Is there a way I can add data into a cookie as is?
I am using my encoding logic and don't want angularjs to do any further encoding on the data.

Edit:
Example:
I want to store the following into a cookie
KdjeI7astAO2l/+cwmoqN1OXjKjLauG7a5Ylf9I57Ok+lmNmp7hBNcqkwAigJGDXbo6TRSJsMaT7jT4EBF1hBA==

using $cookies.mycookie = ...
But AngularJs seems to encode my data to
KdjeI7astAO2l/+cwmoqN1OXjKjLauG7a5Ylf9I57Ok+lmNmp7hBNcqkwAigJGDXbo6TRSJsMaT7jT4EBF1hBA%3D%3D

Is there anyway to have AngularJs store my original data without any modification.

Edit 2:
Also upon further digging I found this link https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3414 which explains that angular is doing encoding when storing cookie. As I previously asked what will be the way to store data in a cookie without this encoding in angular.

Comment: how can anyone guess what you want to do without some representation of it. Question is far too vague...show some code

Comment: I added an example hope that helps explain my problem.

Comment: can get and set own cookie using `document.cookie` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Angular `$cookie` function will `escape` your data when storing a cookie, and `unescape` it when it is retrieved.

If you don't want this to happen, don't use the Angular implementation. You can simply set the cookie yourself using the native browser cookie API, `document.cookie`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie